# How to set name for MeterRegistry httpRequest metrics?

Tags: spring-boot, graphite, micrometer

Good evening all.
I have created GraphiteMeterRegistry bean.

```
@Bean
    public GraphiteMeterRegistry meterRegistry(GraphiteConfig graphiteConfig) {
        String host;
        try {
            host = InetAddress.getLocalHost().getHostName().replaceAll("\\.","_");
        } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
            host = "test";
            log.warn("Host wasn't found", e);
        }

        String prefix = "lm." + host + ".";

        return new GraphiteMeterRegistry(graphiteConfig, Clock.SYSTEM,
                (id, convention) -> prefix + HierarchicalNameMapper.DEFAULT.toHierarchicalName(id, convention));
    }
```

It sends default stas, jvm, hiharicp, http and e.t.c, - that's fine. But when I wanted to get info about httpRequests to my endpoint (called "myendpoint") I have found, that it is stored not in myendpoint folder, but in million folders for each id (got as parametr). For example:

```
myendpoint&id=12345679
myendpoint&id=12345672
myendpoint&id=12345673
myendpoint&id=12345671
```

But I want this name was the same for the same endpoint. How yo configure it?

Comment: is this id in this case a path/query parameter? This should not be added to the metric name in spring boot. Can you share how you are defining the rest endpoint ie. your Controller class?

Answer (score 0):

Spring doc says:

> To customize the tags, and depending on your choice of client, you can
>   provide a @Bean that implements RestTemplateExchangeTagsProvider or
>   WebClientExchangeTagsProvider.

The problem here is if you use servlets, not reactive, you will need to implement not `WebClientExchangeTagsProvider`, but `WebMvcTagsProvider` @Bean.